# Unable to run angular2 application in IE after adjusting polyfills.ts

Tags: angular

I have uncommented all the IE related polyfills.ts file's statement and then made the build of the application but after all it still not working in IE showing error in the console are :

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error 
vendor.bundle.js, line 3281 character 1
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference 
inline.bundle.js, line 55 character 12
```

I am newbie to angular2 so please could anyone suggest any solution for it?

Answer (score -2):

Try Google Chrome Browser Or any other browser. And update your IE.

Comment: i am using IE 9 and above to test. the app is working fine in chrome and firefox.

Comment: That's not really a solution to the OPs problem now, is it?

Comment: Lol. Its a terrible Stack Overflow answer.... but its the answer we all truly need. If only companies would take heed....

Comment: Yet haven't got any solution :(